# Cascading taxonomy term selection widget

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

To be honest, I'm not sure if cascading is the right term, and if it's not then this can just be edited in the future for clarity.

I need a taxonomy term widget that is a drop-down list, and all that is initially populated are the top-level taxonomy terms in the particular vocabulary associated with the widget.  After selecting a top-level term, another drop-down list is added next to the previous (the one you just selected from) with all of the children of the selected term.  The parent drop-down list is then disabled.

You should be able to click a link to go "up a level", basically removing the right-most drop-down list at the time and re-enabling the right-most list after that.

For example, say I have the following structure:

- A

  - AA
  - AB
  - AC
- B

  - BA
  - BB
  - BC
- C

The initial drop-down list would just contain: A, B, and C.  You now select 'A'.  The list with A, B, and C would then become disabled, and another list would be added directly to the right of it with the terms: AA, AB, and AC.

The term submitted along with the form would be the term represented by the right-most disabled list's selection at the time.

Is there anything that exists with this functionality (or similar)?  If so, I haven't seen it (and I'm looking hard).  Otherwise I guess I'll just have to code it up myself, but I'm hoping I don't have to invent a new wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module:

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a
>   greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.